# how to coordinate multiple agents work on a specific question using Langchain?

Tags: openai-api, py-langchain, azure-openai

would you please give some advice about coordinating multiple agents working together.

For example, I defined 2 tools ( A and B), each one has independent function to generate information that can contribute final answers.

The work flow would be: users ask questions, then the question orders agent 1 to call tool A to get information, and then order agent 2 to call tool B to get information, finally all of these information will be wrapped and summarized to get final answer to address users question.

Appreciate that if you would give some advices, the practical example/code is highly appreciated.

Thanks